# Error creating TNS entry for Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a TNS entry for an Oracle database so that I can call SQL*Loader from the command line on that database.

Now from what I've read it appears that I need to create a TNSNAMES.ORA file in my

C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

folder and place the relevant information in there.

I've placed the following in my file

```
 SPEC1=
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = 
     (PROTOCOL = TCP)
     (HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XX)
     (PORT = 1521)
    )
  (CONNECT_DATA = 
   (SERVICE_NAME = SPEC1)
  )
 )
```

Now to test it I've tried calling:

```
tnsping SPEC1
```

but this returns the error:

TNS-0305: Failed to resolve name

I've googled this error and tried the advice but I can't seem to get to the bottom of it. Am I missing something in the code above?

(the tnsping command above looks up a sqlnet.ora file which is in the same folder as the TNSNAMES.ORA file and which references it)

Edit: ok it turns out that I didn't have the full name in the service_name in my tnsnames.ora file and that was the root of my problem.

Comment: have you started the service using lsnrctl ?

Comment: @Satya No, I don't know what that is

Comment: go to command prompt and type lsnrctl SPEC1 START and let me know the output

Comment: 'lsnrctl' is not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: oops my fault , go to $ORACLE_HOME\bin dir and you should be able to find it

Comment: I navigated to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN but that command didn't work there either and there was no file called lsnrctl in there

Comment: I would guess the database is on a different system than your client? If so, the lsnrctl steps listed here are not going to work from your client system.

Comment: Correct! I am using a client only

Answer (score 1):

Try the [EZCONNECT syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT):

```
sqlldr user/pw@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/spec1
```

Comment: Ok this seems to be an improvement. However I'm still gettting an error: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Comment: Are you sure the database is up?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I can connect to it using sql developer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a tnsnames.ora entry.

Have a look at some of the options here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Comment: Sorry but there's so many different options in there I'm not sure where to start. How can I use any of these in conjunction with my SQL * Loader call from the command line?